# how does a sdk client of one org send transaction request to another org endorsing peer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, smartcontracts, chaincode

I have a case where I have hyperledger fabric network two orgs with one endorser peers on each org. there is a write policy that says, 'both the orgs to sign the  transaction to commit the ledger'. in this case how can a client app of one org send transaction request to both the orgs' endorsers? Can a client have identity info from both the orgs which I thing not suggestible.

Please suggest with resource links covered this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperledger fabric has Service Discovery Api for it.

**Service discovery** helps render configurations dynamically which are required to propose transaction,execute chaincode on peer and get endorsement policy associated with chaincode.
Bellow are the links to help you over it.

[read the docs explaination for discovery service](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-overview.html?highlight=discovery)

[node.sdk discovery service tutorial](https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/release-1.4/tutorial-discovery.html)